# Resizing mask file in semantic segmentation - implications

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/) for Multiclass semantic segmentation using DeepLabV3+. My question regards a preprocessing function. In the following block, is it not problematic that resizing the mask image can cause change in original values, if the aspect ratio is different from the original?

```
def read_image(image_path, mask=False):
image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
if mask:
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=1)
    image.set_shape([None, None, 1])
    image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
else:
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image.set_shape([None, None, 3])
    image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
    image = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image)
return image
```

The model runs but I suspect this issue may influence results